# How can I load word2vec vectors?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I have tried lots of different pre-trained models, most of them have 0 documentation the few that have some sort of documentation say that it is possible to load it with

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model102938_that_cannot_be_loaded.bin', binary=True)
```

but it never works and I always get a random error.
Is there actually a way to load it? Or am I better off buying a couple hundred server racks and training it myself?

Comment: What random error?

Comment: The last one i've got was: ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'der'

Comment: `from gensim.models import Word2Vec; Word2Vec.load(...)` doesn't work?

Comment: It actually worked. Thanks man. Don't know how 30+ people with phd are incapable of writing these two lines to the work they published... StackOverflow > Stanford & Google

Comment: Haha, I know how you feel. I've had my own share of problems with gensim. I'll publish an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load w2v models directly using the `gensim.models.Word2Vec` class, like this:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load(...)
```